# split string and form a new string in php

Tags: php, string, split

how do i split a string for example "A,B,C,D" for form into a new string "A B C D" in php?

help much appreciated! explode will form an array, and str_split needs length.

Comment: You could also replace all comma's with whitespaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo implode(" ", explode("," , "A,B,C,D"));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
str_replace(',', ' ', $str)
```

or

```
join(' ', explode(',', $str))
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `str_replace(",", " ", "A,B,C,D");`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = 'A,B,C,D';
$split  = explode(',',$string);  //this will give an array 

$newString = implode(' ',$split); // array mixed with character to form a string /

?>
```